# Having two forest figures and using tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, tikzmark

I have two `forest` figures in the same `figure` environment and I want to use `tikzmark` in both of them. The outcome is supposed to look like this:

[image]

My current code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}                          


\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child
anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,
where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}
}


\newcommand{\spirit}[1]{%
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}%
\ibox{#1}\\[-3.2mm]
\large/\\%
\end{tabular}}}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
        \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt 
        \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\hfill\resizebox{0.47\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{forest}
sn edges, for tree={l sep= 6ex}
[V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \spirit{1}, \spirit{2} }]}
        [\ibox{1} NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                [er]]
        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \spirit{2} } ]}
                [\ibox{2} NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                        [die Äpfel,triangle]]
                [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \ibox{2} } ]}
                        [\tikzmark{ap1}{AP}
                                [ungewaschen]]
                        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \tikzmark{arg11}{\ibox{1}}, \tikzmark{arg12}{\ibox{2}} }]}
                                [isst]]]]]
\end{forest}
}
\hfill\resizebox{0.47\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{forest}
sn edges, for tree={l sep= 6ex}
[V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \spirit{1}, \spirit{2} } ]}
        [\ibox{1} NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                [er]]
        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \spirit{2} } ]}
                [\tikzmark{ap2}{AP}
                        [ungewaschen]]
                [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \tikzmark{arg21}{\ibox{1}}, \spirit{2} } ]}
                        [\ibox{2} NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                                [die Äpfel,triangle]]
                        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \ibox{2} } ]}
                                [isst]]]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->, bend angle=40, bend left] ($(pic cs:ap1)+(1ex,2ex)$) to($(pic cs:arg11)+(1ex,2.5ex)$);
\draw[->, bend angle=40, bend left] ($(pic cs:ap1)+(1ex,2ex)$) to($(pic cs:arg12)+(1ex,2.5ex)$); % 1ex links, 2ex hoch
%
\draw[->, bend angle=40, bend left] ($(pic cs:ap2)+(1ex,2ex)$) to($(pic cs:arg21)+(1ex,2.5ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfill\mbox{}
\caption{Analysis of \emph{dass er die Äpfel ungewaschen isst} and \emph{dass er ungewaschen die Äpfel isst}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to draw the arrows. I put the commands for the first figure after the first figure and the ones for the second figure after the last one, but this did not work. So the current minimal example put all drawing commands after the last figure but this does not work either:

[image]

**Edit:** The solution below worked fine until I updated to texlive 2014 and did all updates. Now I get:

[image]

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had scaled after remembering the coordinates, which is the wrong order:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child
anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,
where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}
}


\newcommand{\spirit}[1]{%
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}%
\ibox{#1}\\[-3.2mm]
\large/\\%
\end{tabular}}}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\upshape\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
        \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt 
        \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{forest}
sn edges, for tree={l sep= 6ex}
[V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \spirit{1}, \spirit{2} }]}
        [\ibox{1} NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                [er]]
        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \spirit{2} } ]}
                [\ibox{2} NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                        [die Äpfel,triangle]]
                [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \ibox{2} } ]}
                        [\tikzmark{ap1}{AP}
                                [ungewaschen]]
                        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \tikzmark{arg11}{\ibox{1}}, \tikzmark{arg12}{\ibox{2}} }]}
                                [isst]]]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
sn edges, for tree={l sep= 6ex}
[V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \spirit{1}, \spirit{2} } ]}
        [\ibox{1} NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                [er]]
        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \spirit{2} } ]}
                [\tikzmark{ap2}{AP}
                        [ungewaschen]]
                [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \tikzmark{arg21}{\ibox{1}}, \spirit{2} } ]}
                        [\ibox{2} NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                                [die Äpfel,triangle]]
                        [V{[{\sc subcat} \sliste{ \ibox{1}, \ibox{2} } ]}
                                [isst]]]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->, bend angle=40, bend left] ($(pic cs:ap1)+(1ex,2ex)$) to($(pic cs:arg11)+(1ex,2.5ex)$);
\draw[->, bend angle=40, bend left] ($(pic cs:ap1)+(1ex,2ex)$) to($(pic cs:arg12)+(1ex,2.5ex)$); % 1ex links, 2ex hoch
%
\draw[->, bend angle=40, bend left] ($(pic cs:ap2)+(1ex,2ex)$) to($(pic cs:arg21)+(1ex,2.5ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\caption{Analysis of \emph{dass er die Äpfel ungewaschen isst} and \emph{dass er ungewaschen die Äpfel isst}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How silly of me! Thanks! I first had two separate tikzpictures in the scalings but then broke it by fixing ...

Comment: A recent update seems to have brooken this (see edit in the question). What now? Shall I ask a new question about this?

Comment: @StefanMüller I just did a full update of TL2014 this morning to check, and it works OK for me.

Comment: Oh, cool: It is a `xelatex` bug. It works with `pdflatex`but it does not with `xelatex`.

Comment: @StefanMüller ah. OK in that case it's definitely a new question:-) or perhaps better to ask on the xetex list. (I can confirm same here)

Comment: @StefanMüller `\sc` is long deprecated.

Comment: Yes, KomaScript tells me the same now every time I run my documents. I started to change this yesterday and it will never appear in examples here. I hope.