# remember picture not working with forest and tikzmark's subnode

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, linguistics, tikz-qtree, tikzmark

According to the [`tikzmark` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf), when using `\subnode`, it should be

> possible to use ordinary node syntax (within a `tikzpicture`) to access this information. Thus after `\node {a \subnode{a}{sub} node};` it is possible to use `a` as a node.

After reading the documentation, using `\subnode` works as I would expect when drawing trees with `tikz-qtree` but not when drawing trees with `forest`.

This code produces the following tree, as desired.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\Tree
[.TP
  [.NP \edge[roof]; {someone} ]
  [.T$'$
    [.\node(T){T};  ]
    [.VP
      [.V$'$
        [.V\\\subnode{eat}{eat}\\{\ldots}\\{\ldots} ]
        [.NP \edge[roof]; {the pie} ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw[->] (T) to[in=-180, out=-75] (eat);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Whereas this code produces the following tree, which is not desired.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} remember picture
[TP
  [NP
    [someone, roof]
  ]
  [T$'$
    [T, name=T]
    [VP
      [V$'$
        [V\\\subnode{eat}{eat}\\\ldots\\\ldots]
        [NP
          [{the pie}, roof]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw[->] (T) to[in=-180, out=-75] (eat);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that `forest` isn't picking up the `remember picture` option, so should I be setting this differently? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is always a bit tricky because there are two separate "remembering" mechanisms at work. So you may just use two subsides and connect them in the usual way, i.e. with an `overlay,remember` picture.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
[TP
  [NP
    [someone, roof]
  ]
  [T$'$
    [\subnode{T}{T}]
    [VP
      [V$'$
        [V\\\subnode{eat}{eat}\\\ldots\\\ldots]
        [NP
          [{the pie}, roof]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->] (T) to[in=-180, out=-75] (eat);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use `\subnodes` only to measure relative positions. This cancels the offset error. One has to account for the `inner sep`, though.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
[TP
  [NP
    [someone, roof]
  ]
  [T$'$
    [T, name=T]
    [VP
      [V$'$
        [\subnode{V1}{V}\\\subnode{eat}{eat}\\\ldots\\\ldots,name=V]
        [NP
          [{the pie}, roof]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw[->] let \p1=($(V1.north west)-(eat.west)$) in  
(T) to[in=-180, out=-75] ($(V.north west)+(0,-\y1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner
ysep})$);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks ... but I should have said this explicitly in the question, I'd like to avoid the separate `tikzpicture`, if possible. Sorry for not making this clear. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: @AdamLiter Presumably it is not impossible but given the complexity of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266743/194703) by the author of the `forest` package I am afraid it may also not be easy. You *can* use `\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->] (T) to[in=-180, out=-75] (eat);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pgfinterruptpicture}` before `\end{forest}` but this is shabby IMHO.