# Using `\subnode` in a tikzpicture with xelatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikzmark

My ultimate goal is to have some portion of text in a tikz node within a tikzpicture and be able to draw arrows to it. I am struggeling with this for over ten years now. cfr suggested I ask the question in a tikz-related way.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]   \node {A node
      with a \subnode{sn}{subnode}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]   
\draw [red,<-] (pic cs:sn) -- ++(0pt,25pt); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

This is the code and when using pdflatex, I get:

[image]

But for xelatex I get no arrow at all.

Ultimately I try to use subnodes in `forest`, but maybe the way is to solve the problem via solving the `tikz` problem first.

These are my earlier questions:
[Drawing lines between parts of nodes in forest trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689886/drawing-lines-between-parts-of-nodes-in-forest-trees)

Comment: Isn't this still the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229500/47927 ?

Comment: Yes. But the comments are too complicated for me. The solution does not have a MWE, so I do not know what to do.

Comment: Well, the solution hasn't become much easier over time, I guess. You should probably rather again try to get in touch with the package maintainer and ask about improvements. I take it that a [bug report has already been submitted](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/354/), and an answer to that links to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339975/47927 which actually should be the solution for your problem.

Comment: [The arrow will be drawn at the wrong position.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sRcK.png) The subnode's position stored in the `aux` file is very different to the one stored by pdflatex. Using the solution linked to by @JasperHabicht seems to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also helped me to solve my original question! https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690425/18561

Comment: I think the linked answer is actually still the way to go. There is no simpler way (yet) as far as I understand this issue. But I have to admit that I don't fully understand *why* this is a solution and where exactly the problem is. The problem seems to be related to the driver, so it is not really related to the `tikzmark` package/library actually.

Comment: I "pinged" the GitHub report here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/353. Let's see... (the good part is that there is no problem in `lualatex` ;-P)

Comment: Ah, yes, I used lualatex sometimes to get workarounds and then safed PDFs which I included into my xelatex files.